# Relation between monads, operads and algebraic theories

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, monads, operads, reference-request

I've begun to interest in algebraic theories and their categorical models: in particular monads, generalized multicategories and operads, lawvere theories and their generalization. Is there any reference that treat systematically the relation between such models of theories, where model means a presentation of theory?

Comment: When you say "such models of theories", it's not clear to me whether you mean model in a more model-theoretic sense (which here would be, e.g., "algebra of a theory") or a way of presenting a theory (so an operad would be "such a model of theory"). I guess you mean the latter though. 

Comment: You guessed right, by the way I've edited the post, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All nice recommendations; some more

#### Lawvere theories and monads

For the connection between monads and Lawvere theories, I've found this a really nice exposition of the $\mathbf{Set}$ case:

> Martin Hyland, John Power - *The category theoretic understanding of universal algebra:       Lawvere theories and monads* - Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science [(pdf at M Hyland's website)](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~martin/Research/Publications/2007/hp07.pdf)

and if what you want is something like the ultimate monads <-> Lawvere theories correspondence:

> Clemens Berger, Paul-André Melliès, Mark Weber - *Monads with arities and their associated theories* [(arXiv)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3064)

Basically all of the *(Lawvere and the like) theories <-> (special) monads* equivalences can be seen as special cases of their general *monad with arities <-> theories with arities* equivalence. This paper is a real joy to read, and how all sort of nerve theorems can be viewed as an instance of the equiv between a monad with arities and the corresponding (generalized) algebraic theory is just wonderful!

Also, on the operadic side, their notion of *homogeneous* theory is related with $T$-operads (with $T$ cartesian *and* local right adjoint), and yields a nice account of *symmetric* operads as homogeneous theories with arities the Segal category $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 12):

Of course, there Tom Leinster's book [Higher Operads, Higher Categories](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CT/0305049), and there's also a lot of stuff on the nLab. Also see Max Kelly's seminal paper (I believe unpublished until recently), [On the operads of J.P. May](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/13/tr13abs.html).

Answer (score 7):

Apart from Todd's recommendations, which I'd second, for monads and Lawvere theories there is Nishizawa and Power, *Lawvere theories enriched over a general base*, JPAA 213, 2009, and the references therein.  I'd also recommend Linton's *An outline of functorial semantics*, LNM 80, 1969 (republished in TAC Reprints).  Lots of people have defined 'generalized multicategories' of one sort or another, going back to Burroni in 1971: Cruttwell and Shulman's *A unified framework for generalized multicategories*, TAC 24(21), 2010, is a useful account.